# Android database copy error

Tags: android, database

i am using publicly available code to copy my pre-populated database to android. The problem is i am getting errors while copying database. It will create the file but the database only contains "android-metadata" table.

This is my ExternalDbOpenHelper class

```
package com.solosus.mhd;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

public class ExternalDbOpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    //Path to the device folder with databases
    public static String DB_PATH;

    //Database file name
    public static String DB_NAME;
    public SQLiteDatabase database;
    public final Context context;

    public SQLiteDatabase getDb() {
        return database;
    }

    public ExternalDbOpenHelper(Context context, String databaseName) {
        super(context, databaseName, null, 1);
        this.context = context;
//Write a full path to the databases of your application
        String packageName = context.getPackageName();
        DB_PATH = String.format("//data//data//%s//databases//", packageName);
        DB_NAME = databaseName;
        openDataBase();
    }

    //This piece of code will create a database if it’s not yet created
    public void createDataBase() {
        boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();
        if (!dbExist) {
           // this.getReadableDatabase();
            SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
            if (db.isOpen()){
                db.close();
            }
            try {
                copyDataBase();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(this.getClass().toString(), "Copying error");
                throw new Error("Error copying database!");
            }
        } else {
            Log.i(this.getClass().toString(), "Database already exists");
        }
    }

    //Performing a database existence check
    public boolean checkDataBase() {
        SQLiteDatabase checkDb = null;
        try {
            String path = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
            checkDb = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(path, null,
                    SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            Log.e(this.getClass().toString(), "Error while checking db");
            Log.d("CHYBA", e.toString());
        }
//Android doesn’t like resource leaks, everything should
        // be closed
        if (checkDb != null) {
            checkDb.close();
        }
        return checkDb != null;
    }

    //Method for copying the database
    private void copyDataBase() throws IOException {
//Open a stream for reading from our ready-made database
//The stream source is located in the assets
//        if (database.isOpen())
//            database.close();

        InputStream externalDbStream = context.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);

//Path to the created empty database on your Android device
        String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;

//Now create a stream for writing the database byte by byte
        OutputStream localDbStream = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

//Copying the database
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int bytesRead;
        while ((bytesRead = externalDbStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            localDbStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        }
//Don’t forget to close the streams
        localDbStream.close();
        externalDbStream.close();
    }

    public SQLiteDatabase openDataBase() throws SQLException {
        String path = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        if (database == null) {
            createDataBase();
            database = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(path, null,
                    SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
        }
        return database;
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void close() {
        if (database != null) {
            database.close();
        }
        super.close();
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {}
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {}


//    public Cursor select(String query) {
//        Cursor c = database.rawQuery(query, null);
//        return c;

    //

//    }

}
```

This is error i am getting (first run of application on emulator - wiped user data, no database exist on the emulator)

```
10-16 09:04:34.8701106-1106/com.solosus.mhd D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 89K, 6% free 2952K/3128K, paused 127ms, total 128ms
10-16 09:04:34.8701106-1106/com.solosus.mhd I/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Grow heap (frag case) to 3.570MB for 635812-byte allocation
10-16 09:04:34.9301106-1115/com.solosus.mhd D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 5% free 3573K/3752K, paused 43ms, total 43ms
10-16 09:04:35.0901106-1106/com.solosus.mhd E/SQLiteLog﹕ (14) cannot open file     at line 30191 of [00bb9c9ce4]
10-16 09:04:35.0901106-1106/com.solosus.mhd E/SQLiteLog﹕ (14) os_unix.c:30191: (2) open(//data//data//com.solosus.mhd//databases//Mhd_nove3.sqlite) -
10-16 09:04:35.1001106-1106/com.solosus.mhd E/SQLiteDatabase﹕ Failed to open database '//data//data//com.solosus.mhd//databases//Mhd_nove3.sqlite'.android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unknown error (code 14): Could not open database
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeOpen(Native Method)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:209)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:193)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.openConnectionLocked(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:463)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:185)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:177)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openInner(SQLiteDatabase.java:804)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.open(SQLiteDatabase.java:789)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:694)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:669)
at com.solosus.mhd.ExternalDbOpenHelper.checkDataBase(ExternalDbOpenHelper.java:67)
at com.solosus.mhd.ExternalDbOpenHelper.createDataBase(ExternalDbOpenHelper.java:44)
at com.solosus.mhd.ExternalDbOpenHelper.openDataBase(ExternalDbOpenHelper.java:110)
at com.solosus.mhd.ExternalDbOpenHelper.<init>(ExternalDbOpenHelper.java:39)
at com.solosus.mhd.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:77)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-16 09:04:35.1001106-1106/com.solosus.mhd E/class com.solosus.mhd.ExternalDbOpenHelper﹕ Error while checking db
10-16 09:04:35.1001106-1106/com.solosus.mhd D/CHYBA﹕ android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unknown error (code 14): Could not open database
10-16 09:04:35.1901106-1106/com.solosus.mhd E/class com.solosus.mhd.ExternalDbOpenHelper﹕ Copying error
10-16 09:04:35.1901106-1106/com.solosus.mhd D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
10-16 09:04:35.2001106-1106/com.solosus.mhd W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb3aa5ba8)
10-16 09:04:35.2001106-1106/com.solosus.mhd E/AndroidRuntime﹕ 
FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: com.solosus.mhd, PID: 1106 java.lang.Error: Error copying database!
at com.solosus.mhd.ExternalDbOpenHelper.createDataBase(ExternalDbOpenHelper.java:55)
at com.solosus.mhd.ExternalDbOpenHelper.openDataBase(ExternalDbOpenHelper.java:110)
at com.solosus.mhd.ExternalDbOpenHelper.<init>(ExternalDbOpenHelper.java:39)
at com.solosus.mhd.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:77)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

After this my app crashes. When i run the app again my app will start but i still get some errors

```
10-16 09:04:34.870 1106-1106/com.solosus.mhd D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 89K, 6% free 2952K/3128K, paused 127ms, total 128ms
10-16 09:04:34.870 1106-1106/com.solosus.mhd I/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Grow heap (frag case) to 3.570MB for 635812-byte allocation
10-16 09:04:34.930 1106-1115/com.solosus.mhd D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 5% free 3573K/3752K, paused 43ms, total 43ms
10-16 09:04:35.090 1106-1106/com.solosus.mhd E/SQLiteLog﹕ (14) cannot open file     at line 30191 of [00bb9c9ce4]
10-16 09:04:35.090 1106-1106/com.solosus.mhd E/SQLiteLog﹕ (14) os_unix.c:30191: (2) open(//data//data//com.solosus.mhd//databases//Mhd_nove3.sqlite) -
10-16 09:04:35.100 1106-1106/com.solosus.mhd E/SQLiteDatabase﹕ Failed to open database '//data//data//com.solosus.mhd//databases//Mhd_nove3.sqlite'.android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unknown error (code 14): Could not open database
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeOpen(Native Method)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:209)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:193)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.openConnectionLocked(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:463)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:185)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:177)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openInner(SQLiteDatabase.java:804)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.open(SQLiteDatabase.java:789)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:694)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:669)
at com.solosus.mhd.ExternalDbOpenHelper.checkDataBase(ExternalDbOpenHelper.java:67)
at com.solosus.mhd.ExternalDbOpenHelper.createDataBase(ExternalDbOpenHelper.java:44)
at com.solosus.mhd.ExternalDbOpenHelper.openDataBase(ExternalDbOpenHelper.java:110)
at com.solosus.mhd.ExternalDbOpenHelper.<init>(ExternalDbOpenHelper.java:39)
at com.solosus.mhd.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:77)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-16 09:04:35.100 1106-1106/com.solosus.mhd E/class com.solosus.mhd.ExternalDbOpenHelper﹕ Error while checking db
10-16 09:04:35.100 1106-1106/com.solosus.mhd D/CHYBA﹕ android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unknown error (code 14): Could not open database
10-16 09:04:35.190 1106-1106/com.solosus.mhd E/class com.solosus.mhd.ExternalDbOpenHelper﹕ Copying error
10-16 09:04:35.190 1106-1106/com.solosus.mhd D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
10-16 09:04:35.200 1106-1106/com.solosus.mhd W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb3aa5ba8)
10-16 09:04:35.200 1106-1106/com.solosus.mhd E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.solosus.mhd, PID: 1106
java.lang.Error: Error copying database!
at com.solosus.mhd.ExternalDbOpenHelper.createDataBase(ExternalDbOpenHelper.java:55)
at com.solosus.mhd.ExternalDbOpenHelper.openDataBase(ExternalDbOpenHelper.java:110)
at com.solosus.mhd.ExternalDbOpenHelper.<init>(ExternalDbOpenHelper.java:39)
at com.solosus.mhd.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:77)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-16 09:17:17.542 1272-1272/com.solosus.mhd D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 70K, 5% free 2952K/3108K, paused 77ms, total 78ms
10-16 09:17:17.542 1272-1272/com.solosus.mhd I/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Grow heap (frag case) to 3.570MB for 635812-byte allocation
10-16 09:17:17.572 1272-1281/com.solosus.mhd D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2K, 5% free 3570K/3732K, paused 26ms, total 26ms
10-16 09:17:17.682 1272-1272/com.solosus.mhd I/class com.solosus.mhd.ExternalDbOpenHelper﹕ Database already exists
10-16 09:17:17.712 1272-1272/com.solosus.mhd I/class com.solosus.mhd.ExternalDbOpenHelper﹕ Database already exists
10-16 09:17:17.802 1272-1272/com.solosus.mhd I/class com.solosus.mhd.ExternalDbOpenHelper﹕ Database already exists
10-16 09:17:17.902 1272-1272/com.solosus.mhd D/﹕ HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb84be4b0, tid 1272
10-16 09:17:17.972 1272-1272/com.solosus.mhd W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
10-16 09:17:17.982 1272-1272/com.solosus.mhd D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
```

Now i can see in DDMS that database file has been created on the device but it does not contain any tables except "android-metadata". 
I debugged the app and the problem was when method copyDatabase() was called it only executed first line and then jumped to catch statement from where the method was called

```
 private void copyDataBase() throws IOException {
//Open a stream for reading from our ready-made database
//The stream source is located in the assets
//        if (database.isOpen())
//            database.close(); i saw some tip to add this but it did not work

        InputStream externalDbStream = context.getAssets().open(DB_NAME); // after this line it jumps to catch-statement, the rest of the method is not executed.
```

This is the method which calls copyDataBase()

```
public void createDataBase() {
    boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();
    if (!dbExist) {
       // this.getReadableDatabase();
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        if (db.isOpen()){
            db.close();
        }
        try {
            copyDataBase();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(this.getClass().toString(), "Copying error"); // after copyDataBase() first line it jumps right here
            throw new Error("Error copying database!");
        }
    } else {
        Log.i(this.getClass().toString(), "Database already exists");
    }
}
```

I am kinda stuck cause i dont know what i am doing wrong. I am not a pro but i would like to ask what to fix here. I debugged it milion times and could not find what exactly is wrong. Thanks for any tips. 
EDIT: Forgot to mention that my database is currently called Mhd_nove3.sqlite and is located in res directory.

Comment: `copy my pre-populated database to android.` I did not look in your code to find out where the pre-populated databes resides when you start your copy action nor did i look where you would exactly copy the database to as i would like to hear that from you.

Comment: my database is located in res directory and i copy it to data directory as in this command
DB_PATH = String.format("//data//data//%s//databases//", packageName);

Comment: It fails because Android already creates a DB for you when you open it, and thus the file already exists. Also replacing over and existing open DB will give you errors, because Android DB wrappers are now in inconsistent state in relation to existing DB. You should copy it **before** opening.

Comment: `"//data//data//%s//databases//"` is wrong. It should be `"/data/data/%s/databases/"`. Only if you you used backslashes you had to double them in a string. I did not look further in your code. Please try this first. meanwhile you could report where your code stucks c.q. produces errors.

Comment: @m0skit0 So i tried to make sure that copyDatabase executes before any database opening (i simply only checked if file exist and did not try to open it), this produced slightly different error but still there was error. Also there was no database created (i checked in DDMS file manager).
I also tried to change copy destination to what greenapps suggested but did not help.
I debugged it again and still i can not get past this line
InputStream externalDbStream = context.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);
from there it always jumps to catch statement and crashes

Comment: @greenapps `//data//data//%s//databases//` is not wrong, just unnecessary. Linux handles several `/` as one.

Comment: @Solosus First you should log the stacktrace of the exception so we can have more information. Next, where are you storing your DB file in the project? Are you sure DB_NAME has no typos?

Comment: @m0skit0 Thanks for pointing out stacktrace. I did that and saw that the error was FileNotFound. It could not locate my DB file inside res folder. I moved it to /assets folder and changed code to context.getAssets(). Everything works now. Thanks for help